# Unity: Instantiated Object gets always the rotation of the spawner Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a zombie. When he dies, he should spawn a shotgun munition package, which the player can collect.

I want the rotation of the shotgunMunition to be 0, 0, 0.

So i used Quaternion.identity, but the munition gets always spawned with the rotation of the zombie.

This is my code:

```
Instantiate(shotgunMuni, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

What i tried yet:

- trying to use "Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,0)) instead - didn't work, same result.
- Google for a solution, but mostly they write "use Quaternion.identity" - i am using it..

Comment: Is this really all the relevant code? Are you making any changes to the spawned instance after spawning? What does `shotgunMuni` refer to, prefab or child of zombie? If it refers to a child, does that child have any logic that might change its rotation?

Comment: Is the instantiated object a child of the zombie? You can check this in the Hierarchy-Tab after you click play and trigger the instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If shotgunMuni is a child of a rotated object a rotation of zero will have it rotated to it's parents rotation. In your case it might be a child of zombie and therefore rotated.
I can think of three ways to get your ammunition spawned with zero rotation.

1. Set the global rotation after instantiating your object.

   ```
   GameObject shotgunMuniInstance = Instantiate(shotgunMuni, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
   shotgunMuniInstance.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero; // This is in global space
   ```
2. Rotate the child object by the negative rotation of it's parent.
3. Have a seperate transform as a parent for your ammunition which has zero rotation.